# How to gather item data from different pages in scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, function, web-scraping, scrapy

I tried to collect data from a webpage about quotes and then click in the about author sections to collect more data from that page, and I want it to be stored in same row in the item class of scrapy.

code :

```py
    def parse(self, response):
        qs = response.css('.quote')
        self.quote_item = QuotesItem()

        for q in qs:
            page_url = q.css('span a').attrib['href']
            full_page_url = 'https://quotes.toscrape.com' + page_url

            # tags
            t = []
            tags = q.css('.tag')
            for tag in tags:
                t.append(tag.css('::text').get())

            # items

            self.quote_item['quote'] = q.css('.text ::text').get(),
            self.quote_item['tag'] = t,
            self.quote_item['author'] = q.css('span .author ::text').get(),
            yield response.follow(full_page_url, callback=self.parse_page, cb_kwargs={'item': self.quote_item})
            yield self.quote_item




    def parse_page(self, response, item):
        q = response.css('.author-details')
        n = {}
        n['birth_date'] = q.css('p .author-born-date ::text').get()
        n['birth_location'] = q.css('p .author-born-location ::text').get()
        item.update(n)
```

As a result the data collected doesn't include `birth_date` and `birth_location`.
Output example:

```py
{"quote": ["“One good thing about music, when it hits you, you feel no pain.”"], "tag": [["music"]], "author": ["Bob Marley"]}
```

I'm looking if there is a way that I can add the output of second function to first without creating a new row (I tried to yield the output from second function that will make it show as a new line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to create an item every iteration.
2. Yield the item in the last callback method.
3. Next time search SO first, it was answered multiple times already.

```py
def parse(self, response):
    qs = response.css('.quote')
    
    for q in qs:
        page_url = q.css('span a').attrib['href']
        full_page_url = 'https://quotes.toscrape.com' + page_url

        # tags
        t = []
        tags = q.css('.tag')
        for tag in tags:
            t.append(tag.css('::text').get())

        # items
        quote_item = QuotesItem()
        quote_item['quote'] = q.css('.text ::text').get(),
        quote_item['tag'] = t,
        quote_item['author'] = q.css('span .author ::text').get(),
        yield response.follow(full_page_url, callback=self.parse_page, cb_kwargs={'item': quote_item})


def parse_page(self, response, item):
    q = response.css('.author-details')    
    item['birth_date'] = q.css('p .author-born-date ::text').get()
    item['birth_location'] = q.css('p .author-born-location ::text').get()
    yield item
```